# Java JSON parse array

Tags: java, json

I am using the following library to parse an object:

```
{"name": "web", "services": []}
```

And the following code

```
import com.json.parsers.JSONParser;


JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parseJson(stringJson);
```

when the array services is empty, it displays the following error

```
@Key-Heirarchy::root/services[0]/   @Key::  Value is expected but found empty...@Position::29
```

if the array services has an element everything works fine

```
{"name": "web", "services": ["one"]}
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Step 1: use jackson http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome   Step 2: Thank me later.

Comment: +1 for Jackson. Drop-dat-lib.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser`
Something like this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringJson);
```

Now to access the fields, you can do this:

```
JSONObject name = jsonObject.get("name"); //gives you 'web'
```

And `services` is a JSONArray, so fetch it in JSONArray. Like this:

```
JSONArray services = jsonObject.get("services");
```

Now, you can iterate through this `services` JSONArray as well.

```
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = services.iterator();
// iterate through json array
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   // do something. Fetch fields in services array.
 }
```

Hope this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need parser?
try this:-

```
String stringJson = "{\"name\": \"web\", \"services\": []}";
JSONObject obj = JSONObject.fromObject(stringJson);
System.out.println(obj);
System.out.println(obj.get("name"));
System.out.println(obj.get("services"));
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("services");
System.out.println(arr.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problen with https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json

Reading JSON

Read a JSON object or array from a Reader or a String:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom( jsonString );
JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.readFrom( jsonReader );
```

Access the contents of a JSON object:

```
String name = jsonObject.get( "name" ).asString();
int age = jsonObject.get( "age" ).asInt(); // asLong(), asFloat(), asDouble(), ...
```

Access the contents of a JSON array:

```
String name = jsonArray.get( 0 ).asString();
int age = jsonArray.get( 1 ).asInt(); // asLong(), asFloat(), asDouble(), ...
```